# What is the Equivalent code From array_push in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, equivalent

Hi guys I need the equivalent java code of this PHP code:

```
<?php
  $stack = array("orange", "banana");
  array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
  print_r($stack);
?>
```

the Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("orange");
list.add("banana");
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Java and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

That would be `add(Element)` method for an ArrayList.

For an array, you have to manually say at which index, what element:

```
String[] word = new String[5];
word[4] = "raspberry";
```

Or

```
String[] word = {"orange","banana","raspberry","srtrawberry"};
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a close equivalent:

```
import java.util.*;

List stack = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("orange", "banana"));
Collections.addAll(stack, "apple", "raspberry");
System.out.println(stack);
```

Comment: You will get ConcurrentModificationException when trying to add elements to your stack as Arrays.asList() returns unmodifieable Arrayl.ArrayList, not regular java.util.ArrayList.
In this situation you should use List stack = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("orange", "banana"));